# Import CSV file with mixed data types

Tags: parsing, matlab, file-io, csv, import

I'm working with MATLAB for few days and I'm having difficulties to import a CSV-file to a matrix.

My problem is that my CSV-file contains almost only Strings and some integer values, so that `csvread()` doesn't work. `csvread()` only gets along with integer values.

How can I store my strings in some kind of a 2-dimensional array to have free access to each element?

Here's a sample CSV for my needs:

```
04;abc;def;ghj;klm;;;;;
;;;;;Test;text;0xFF;;
;;;;;asdfhsdf;dsafdsag;0x0F0F;;
```

The main thing are the empty cells and the texts within the cells.
As you see, the structure may vary.

Comment: Have a look at textscan > http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/textscan.html

Comment: you should post a couple of rows from your CSV file so that we get an idea how the file is structured (are the strings quoted with `'` or `"`, do they contain commas inside the quotations, are the integer values quoted as well, is there any escaped delimiters such as `"this is \"an example\""` etc...)

Comment: Done :) I hope it helps a little bit

Answer (score 51, accepted):

For the case when you know how many columns of data there will be in your CSV file, one simple call to [`textscan`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/textscan.html) like [Amro suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4818390/52738) will be your best solution.

However, if you don't know *a priori* how many columns are in your file, you can use a more general approach like I did in the following function. I first used the function [`fgetl`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fgetl.html) to read each line of the file into a cell array. Then I used the function [`textscan`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/textscan.html) to parse each line into separate strings using a predefined field delimiter and treating the integer fields as strings for now (they can be converted to numeric values later). Here is the resulting code, placed in a function `read_mixed_csv`:

```
function lineArray = read_mixed_csv(fileName, delimiter)

  fid = fopen(fileName, 'r');         % Open the file
  lineArray = cell(100, 1);           % Preallocate a cell array (ideally slightly
                                      %   larger than is needed)
  lineIndex = 1;                      % Index of cell to place the next line in
  nextLine = fgetl(fid);              % Read the first line from the file
  while ~isequal(nextLine, -1)        % Loop while not at the end of the file
    lineArray{lineIndex} = nextLine;  % Add the line to the cell array
    lineIndex = lineIndex+1;          % Increment the line index
    nextLine = fgetl(fid);            % Read the next line from the file
  end
  fclose(fid);                        % Close the file

  lineArray = lineArray(1:lineIndex-1);              % Remove empty cells, if needed
  for iLine = 1:lineIndex-1                          % Loop over lines
    lineData = textscan(lineArray{iLine}, '%s', ...  % Read strings
                        'Delimiter', delimiter);
    lineData = lineData{1};                          % Remove cell encapsulation
    if strcmp(lineArray{iLine}(end), delimiter)      % Account for when the line
      lineData{end+1} = '';                          %   ends with a delimiter
    end
    lineArray(iLine, 1:numel(lineData)) = lineData;  % Overwrite line data
  end

end
```

Running this function on the sample file content from the question gives this result:

```
>> data = read_mixed_csv('myfile.csv', ';')

data = 

  Columns 1 through 7

    '04'    'abc'    'def'    'ghj'    'klm'    ''            ''        
    ''      ''       ''       ''       ''       'Test'        'text'    
    ''      ''       ''       ''       ''       'asdfhsdf'    'dsafdsag'

  Columns 8 through 10

    ''          ''    ''
    '0xFF'      ''    ''
    '0x0F0F'    ''    ''
```

The result is a 3-by-10 cell array with one field per cell where missing fields are represented by the empty string `''`. Now you can access each cell or a combination of cells to format them as you like. For example, if you wanted to change the fields in the first column from strings to integer values, you could use the function [`str2double`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/str2double.html) as follows:

```
>> data(:, 1) = cellfun(@(s) {str2double(s)}, data(:, 1))

data = 

  Columns 1 through 7

    [  4]    'abc'    'def'    'ghj'    'klm'    ''            ''        
    [NaN]    ''       ''       ''       ''       'Test'        'text'    
    [NaN]    ''       ''       ''       ''       'asdfhsdf'    'dsafdsag'

  Columns 8 through 10

    ''          ''    ''
    '0xFF'      ''    ''
    '0x0F0F'    ''    ''
```

Note that the empty fields results in [`NaN`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/nan.html) values.

Comment: See also @AndyCampbell's solution below for more recent releases of Matlab: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19642332/232610

Comment: Nice one. Textscan does not like empty inputs though. If the scanned csv file has empty rows, the procedure fails. I would advise replacing

`lineArray = lineArray(1:lineIndex-1);`

by 

`ind              = all(cellfun(@isempty,lineArray),2);  `
`lineArray     = lineArray(~ind);`

Comment: You can also use `strsplit()` with the  `CollapseDelimiters` parameter set to `false` to tokenize each line of the csv file. Matlab, by default, collapses consecutive delimiters. Set to false, the result is this: `{'' '' '' '' '' 'Test' 'text' '0xFF' '' ''}` for the command `strsplit(';;;;;Test;text;0xFF;;', ';', 'CollapseDelimiters', false)`

Answer (score 20):

Given the sample you posted, this simple code should do the job:

```
fid = fopen('file.csv','r');
C = textscan(fid, repmat('%s',1,10), 'delimiter',';', 'CollectOutput',true);
C = C{1};
fclose(fid);
```

Then you could format the columns according to their type. For example if the first column is all integers, we can format it as such:

```
C(:,1) = num2cell( str2double(C(:,1)) )
```

Similarly, if you wish to convert the 8th column from hex to decimals, you can use HEX2DEC:

```
C(:,8) = cellfun(@hex2dec, strrep(C(:,8),'0x',''), 'UniformOutput',false);
```

The resulting cell array looks as follows:

```
C = 
    [  4]    'abc'    'def'    'ghj'    'klm'    ''            ''                []    ''    ''
    [NaN]    ''       ''       ''       ''       'Test'        'text'        [ 255]    ''    ''
    [NaN]    ''       ''       ''       ''       'asdfhsdf'    'dsafdsag'    [3855]    ''    ''
```

Answer (score 14):

In R2013b or later you can use a table:

```
>> table = readtable('myfile.txt','Delimiter',';','ReadVariableNames',false)
>> table = 

    Var1    Var2     Var3     Var4     Var5        Var6          Var7         Var8      Var9    Var10
    ____    _____    _____    _____    _____    __________    __________    ________    ____    _____

      4     'abc'    'def'    'ghj'    'klm'    ''            ''            ''          NaN     NaN  
    NaN     ''       ''       ''       ''       'Test'        'text'        '0xFF'      NaN     NaN  
    NaN     ''       ''       ''       ''       'asdfhsdf'    'dsafdsag'    '0x0F0F'    NaN     NaN
```

Here is [more info](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/tables.html).

Answer (score 7):

Use xlsread, it works just as well on .csv files as it does on .xls files. Specify that you want three outputs:

```
[num char raw] = xlsread('your_filename.csv')
```

and it will give you an array containing only the numeric data (num), an array containing only the character data (char) and an array that contains all data types in the same format as the .csv layout (raw).

Answer (score 6):

Have you tried to use the "CSVIMPORT" function found in the file exchange? I haven't tried it myself, but it claims to handle all combinations of text and numbers.

http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/23573-csvimport

Answer (score 4):

Depending on the format of your file, **importdata** might work.

You can store Strings in a cell array. Type "doc cell" for more information.

Comment: A cell array is what OP needs. OP could even store the integer data in there.

Comment: Hi William, "cell" seems to be a very good data structure for my issue. The only thing I am not getting along with is "importdata", because it doesnt read in empty cells(from my CSV) at the beginning of a line...I only get an "[1x89  char]" imported.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend looking at the dataset array.

The dataset array is a data type that ships with Statistics Toolbox.
It is specifically designed to store hetrogeneous data in a single container.

The Statistics Toolbox demo page contains a couple vidoes that show some of the dataset array features.  The first is titled "An Introduction to Dataset Arrays". The second is titled "An Introduction to Joins".

http://www.mathworks.com/products/statistics/demos.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the examples look very useful, but in my case i have no Statistics Toolbox installed :/

Comment: See my answer below, if you have R2013b this solution becomes doing this with a table.

Answer (score 1):

If your input file has a fixed amount of columns separated by commas and you know in which columns are the strings it might be best to use the function

```
textscan()
```

Note that you can specify a format where you read up to a maximum number of characters in the string or until a delimiter (comma) is found.

Answer (score 0):

```
% Assuming that the dataset is ";"-delimited and each line ends with ";"
fid = fopen('sampledata.csv');
tline = fgetl(fid);
u=sprintf('%c',tline); c=length(u);
id=findstr(u,';'); n=length(id);
data=cell(1,n);
for I=1:n
    if I==1
        data{1,I}=u(1:id(I)-1);
    else
        data{1,I}=u(id(I-1)+1:id(I)-1);
    end
end
ct=1;
while ischar(tline)
    ct=ct+1;
    tline = fgetl(fid);
    u=sprintf('%c',tline);
    id=findstr(u,';');
    if~isempty(id)
        for I=1:n
            if I==1
                data{ct,I}=u(1:id(I)-1);
            else
                data{ct,I}=u(id(I-1)+1:id(I)-1);
            end
        end
    end
end
fclose(fid);
```