# Evaluate variables in external file strings

Tags: matlab, types, import, evaluation

## Issue

I want to import a CSV file with mixed data types of numbers and variables/symbols. The import part was already discussed in [Import CSV file with mixed data types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4747834/matlab-import-csv-file-with-mixed-data-types).

### Description

The CSV file here contains only 2x2 formulas (but in general 64x64 and I evaluate it 1'000'000 times).
The problem that I was facing is the evaluation of the cells. This can not be done in the same way.

The matlab code is something like

```
% Parameter initialization
vector1 = ones(1e6);
a=1;
b=2;
c=3;
d=4;

% Formula calculation
vector2(1)=import('input000001.csv');
```

where my minimal input file `input000001.csv` contains some formula, as e.g.:

```
a*vector1(1),2*vector1(1)/b
c+vector1(1),3*vector1(1)^d
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
[a b c d] = deal(1,2,3,4);

data = strcat(importdata('input.csv', sprintf('\n')), ';');
Matrix = eval(['[' data{:} '[]]']);
```

EDIT: To avoid slowdown by `eval` you can write the string in another m-file and call it instead in the loop. Something like this:

```
[a b c d] = deal(1,2,3,4);

matDef = regexprep(fileread('input.csv'), {'(\r\n|\r|\n)' ';^'}, {';' ''});
f = fopen('inputMatrix.m', 'w');
fwrite(f, ['Matrix = [' matDef '];'])
fclose(f);
rehash

for k=1:100000,
    inputMatrix
end
```

You need the `rehash` to ask matlab to add newly-created `inputMatrix` to list of known functions.

Comment: @strpeter Glad that it worked. You can choose that as an answer then.

Comment: Nevertheless, the routine does not work as fast as by copy-pasting the data from `input.csv`... Is there a way to optimize this?

Comment: How big is your file? How long it takes for each line to run? I suspect the `eval` takes longer time than the import. In that case there is not much to do, because even after copy-paste, when you run the code you have to spend that much time for Matlab to evaluate the matrix.

Comment: My file is only 16x16 (with generalization 64x64) but I evaluate it 1'000'000 times. After import you still have to apply eval to the string which I can avoid by copy-pasting. Result: The code slows down by more than a factor of 24!

Comment: @strpeter Added an alternative solution to avoid `eval`.

Comment: It seems to work until the last line where the last entry is missing: Matrix = [a,b;c,];

Comment: It's because your csv file ends with no EOL. I updated the regexp pattern to cover that. Also added `rehash` so that it works even if the `inputMatrix.m` does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

After some hints I achieved to come around with the following solution.

```
%% Initialization
a=1;
b=2;
c=3;
d=4;

%% Procedure for input and evaluation
Temp = cell(read_mixed_csv('input.csv',','));
[imax,jmax]=size(Temp);
Matrix = zeros(imax,jmax);
for i = (1:imax)
    for j = (1:jmax)
        Matrix(i,j) = eval(Temp{i,j});
    end
end
```

where `read_mixed_csv('input.csv',',')` is from [Import CSV file with mixed data types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4747834/matlab-import-csv-file-with-mixed-data-types/4801735#4801735).

I am open for better answers!

Comment: I am interested in knowing why you save lines of code into a .csv, or you do not have control over the .csv generation?

Comment: I generated the .csv file by myselve: It is an export of a `Table` from Mathematica, result of some analytical treatment. As I want to do now more efficient calculations with the matrix, I want to hand the matrix over to MATLAB.