# MATLAB: Get the last modification time of a file

Tags: matlab, timestamp

I am looking for MATLAB code that does some routine (updates a `file.m`), if `file.csv` is edited more recently than `file.m`.

Something that should look like:

```
% Write time extraction
tempC     = GetFileTime('file.csv', [], 'Write');
tempdateC = tempC.date
tempM     = GetFileTime('file.m', [], 'Write');
tempdateM = tempM.date

% Write time comparison
if numel(dir('file.m')) == 0 || tempdateC >= tempdateM
    matDef = regexprep(fileread('file.csv'), '(\r\n|\r|\n)', ';\n');
    f = fopen('file.m', 'w');
    fwrite(f, ['Variable = [' matDef(1:end) '];']);
    fclose(f);
end
```

The lines for timestamp extraction seem to be incorrect MATLAB code. The rest works ([Evaluate variables in external file strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17328383/matlab-evaluate-variable-in-string)).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can extract the modification time of a file using MATLAB's [`dir`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/dir.html) command. Something like:

```
function modTime = GetFileTime(fileName)
listing = dir(fileName);
% check we got a single entry corresponding to the file
assert(numel(listing) == 1, 'No such file: %s', fileName);
modTime = listing.datenum;
end
```

Note that the output is in MATLAB's [`datenum`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/datenum.html) serial date format.