# Automatically counting number of saves in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to automatically count the number of times I edit and save an mfile in MATLAB, so that I can keep track of the number of edits I make to a bunch of scripts. Is there a way of doing this automatically within MATLAB using some sort of counter, so that the number of saves appears within the mfile?

e.g.

```
function [output] = dummyfn(input)
% Saves = 2
output=log(input)+input;
end
```

If I then edit dummyfn.m by converting the + to a * and save, it'll appear as the following next time I open the function:

```
function [output] = dummyfn(input)
% Saves = 3
output=log(input)*input;
end
```

Comment: I'm not sure why you want to do this, but I suggest using version control instead.

Comment: I want to use this alongside version control as changes to these scripts are frequent. I will only commit final changes every week or so.

Comment: You may use a local repository which contains all your changes and a remote repository which is updated weekly. Matlab has no revision control.

Comment: is there a system function that can be called to matlab to do this just out of interest? I will consider using a local and remote repo.

Comment: I also can't see the value in this. You might be able to hack a bit of solution using persistent variables and the modification time (see [`dir`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17522463/matlab-get-the-last-modification-time-of-a-file)). Otherwise a real solution will require calling system functions to detect actual saves (`opensnoop` on Linux and OS X comes to mind). What OS are you using?

Comment: Mac OS X 10.7. I'm just trying to keep track of the number of times I edit regardless of network access - this seems like a simple way of achieving this.

Comment: I would create a custom save function (a new button on the toolbar) which calls a script that updates a counter that's embedded in my file. You can see examples of how to do that at http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/316678