# Matlab - Read csv file with complex strings

Tags: matlab, csv

I have a `csv` file with lines such as:

```
"some text", "more text hello 392 392", "etc complicated string here with spaces and commas"
```

How can I read this file in as a big matrix?

Comment: Are you really asking for `["some text", "more text hello 392 392", "etc complicated string here with spaces and commas"]`? This is a 1x82 char array. Probably you are looking for a 1x3 cell? `{"some text", "more text hello 392 392", "etc complicated string here with spaces and commas"}`

Comment: yes, that is right - sorry

Comment: To make it easier...I just want to read it in as a bix matrix

Comment: possible duplicate: [MATLAB: Import CSV file with mixed data types](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4747834/238644)

Comment: @DangKhoa Doesn't look like a duplicate. Yes, both questions discuss CSV files, but their format is very different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion, the most sensible approach would be to use regular expressions to match the correct pattern (pairs of quotation marks and commas):

```
%// Read lines as strings
fid = fopen('input.txt', 'r');
C = textscan(fid, '%s', 'Delimiter', '\n');
fclose(fid);

%// Tokenize each line using a regular expression
C = cellfun(@(x){[x{:}]}, regexp(C{:}, '"([^"]*)"(?:\s*,\s*)?', 'tokens'));
```

The resulting cell array `C` should contain all desired comma-separated values as tokens.

#### Example

Suppose your file is named "input.csv", and contains the following:

```
"some text", "more text hello 392 392", "string spaces and commas ,,,"
"hello, world!"
```

After:

```
fid = fopen('input.csv', 'r');
C = textscan(fid, '%s', 'Delimiter', '\n');
fclose(fid);
C = cellfun(@(x){[x{:}]}, regexp(C{:}, '"([^"]*)"(?:\s*,\s*)?', 'tokens'));
```

the result should be:

```
C(1, 1) =
    'some text'
    'more text hello 392 392'
    'string spaces and commas ,,,'

C(1, 2) = 
    'hello, world!'
```

Answer (score 0):

Thus you are asking for simple text reading?

```
fid=fopen('dummy.csv');
a=[];
while(1) ;
    tline = fgetl(fid);
    if ~ischar(tline)
        break;
    end
    a=[a;char(tline)];
end
fclose(fid);
```