# Matlab - preprocess CSV file

Tags: matlab, csv

I have a CSV file in a format similar to the following one:

```
title1 
index   columnA1  columnA2  columnA3
1       2         3         6
2       23        23        1
3       2         3         45
4       2         2         101
title2 
index   columnB1  columnB2  columnB3
1       23        53        6
2       22        13        1
3       5         4         43
4       8         6         102
```

I want to build a function `readCustomCSV` which receives a CSV file in the bellow illustrated format and a row index `i` and returns an output file with (for let's say `i = 3`) the following content:

```
title1 
index   columnA1  columnA2  columnA3
3       2         3         45
title2 
index   columnB1  columnB2  columnB3
3       5         4         43
```

Do you know how to use the `csvread` function in order to obtain this type of functionality?

It confuses me that there are 2 types sections. I was thinking at using the whole thing as a string and then split it into 2 .csv files and then read the corresponding line line.

Comment: Note that `csvread` requires that the CSV file contains purely numeric data. Take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4747834/matlab-import-csv-file-with-mixed-data-types). The highest and accepted answer gives you a function `read_mixed_csv` that will let you import the entire CSV file as a cell matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using this function : 
I assumed that all tables have equal number of columns/rows. The code can definitely be shortened / improved / extended ;)

```
function multi_table_csvread (row_index)
filename_INPUT = 'multi_table.csv' ;
filename_OUTPUT = 'selected_row.csv' ;
fIN = fopen(filename_INPUT,'r');
nextLine = fgetl(fIN);
tableIndex = 0;
tableLine = 0;
csvTable = [];
% start reading the csv file, line by line
while nextLine ~= -1
    lineStr =  strtrim(strsplit(nextLine,',')) ;
    % remove empty cells 
    lineStr(cellfun('isempty',lineStr)) = [] ; 
    tableLine = tableLine + 1 ;
    % if 1 element start new table
    if numel(lineStr) == 1
        tableIndex = tableIndex + 1;
        tableLine = 1;
        csvTable{tableIndex,tableLine} = lineStr ;
    else
        lineStr = add_comas(lineStr) ;
        csvTable{tableIndex,tableLine} = lineStr ;
    end
    nextLine = fgetl(fIN);
end
fclose(fIN);
fOUT = fopen(filename_OUTPUT,'w');
if row_index > size(csvTable,2) -2
    error('The row index exceeds the maximum number of rows!')
end
for k = 1 : size(csvTable,1)
    title = csvTable{k,1};
    columnHeaders = csvTable{k,2};
    selected_row = csvTable{k,row_index+2};
    fprintf(fOUT,'%s\n',title{:});
    fprintf(fOUT,'%s',columnHeaders{:});
    fprintf(fOUT,'\n');
    fprintf(fOUT,'%s',selected_row{:});
    fprintf(fOUT,'\n');
end
fclose(fOUT);

function line_with_comas = add_comas(this_line)

for ii = 1 : length(this_line)-1
    this_line{ii} = strcat(this_line{ii},',') ;
end
line_with_comas = this_line ;
```