# Reading large file in matlab with unique data format

Tags: matlab

I am dealing with loading data from 250 MB csv file into Matlab. The Data looks as following:

```
Col1    Col2           Col3     Col4        Col5    
1       5/1/2014       1       18.4765      18.1938
```

When I do something like:

```
y = csvread('DataFile.csv');
```

The second column is date and hence when I use csvread, the variable y appears as following:

```
1   2014    -5  -1  1   18.4765000000000    18.1938000000000
0   0        0   0  0   0                   0
```

So, the problems I am dealing with are:

(1) The dates get messed up
(2) an extra row with zeros gets added

How do I read such data file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From csvread documentation: Read comma-separated value file

your csv file contains contents besides values.

If you have Microsoft Excel you can try using xlsread: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/xlsread.html

```
[num,txt,raw] = xlsread('myfile.xls');
```

Otherwise it would most likely have to be done manually, you can try the function from this answer:

[Import CSV file with mixed data types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4747834/import-csv-file-with-mixed-data-types)