# Import Mixed CSV that has quotes around text

Tags: matlab, csv, import

I am importing a CSV file that is comma delimited into MATLAB. Each column has quotes around anything I want to consider as text and then a comma.

I am using read_mixed_csv function from the answer to this question to read in the data as a cell: [Import CSV file with mixed data types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4747834/import-csv-file-with-mixed-data-types)

```
thisdata = read_mixed_csv(fname, ','); % Reads in the CSV file 
thisdata = regexprep(thisdata, '^"|"$','');
```

However, since a few of my columns look like this:

```
"FAIRHOPE, Alabama"
"FAIRHOPE HIGH SCHOOL, FAIRHOPE,  ALABAMA"
"Daphne-Fairhope-Foley, AL"
```

MATLAB places everything after a comma into a new column. So

```
"Daphne-Fairhope-Foley, AL"
```

Becomes two columns

```
"Daphne-Fairhope-Foley
AL"
```

**How can I get MATLAB to read in a mixed csv file and not only consider a comma as a delimiter, but also consider the quotation marks?** Is there a more automated way of doing it than `textscan`? If `textscan` is an option, what would that look like?

Here is a sample of the data I'm trying to read in with the header included:

```
"State Code","County Code","Site Num","Parameter Code","POC","Latitude","Longitude","Datum","Parameter Name","Sample Duration","Pollutant Standard","Date Local","Units of Measure","Event Type","Observation Count","Observation Percent","Arithmetic Mean","1st Max Value","1st Max Hour","AQI","Method Name","Local Site Name","Address","State Name","County Name","City Name","CBSA Name","Date of Last Change"
"01","003","0010","88101",1,30.498001,-87.881412,"NAD83","PM2.5 - Local Conditions","24 HOUR","PM25 24-hour 2006","2013-01-01","Micrograms/cubic meter (LC)","None",1,100.0,7.3,7.3,0,30,"R & P Model 2025 PM2.5 Sequential w/WINS - GRAVIMETRIC","FAIRHOPE, Alabama","FAIRHOPE HIGH SCHOOL, FAIRHOPE,  ALABAMA","Alabama","Baldwin","Fairhope","Daphne-Fairhope-Foley, AL","2014-02-11"
"01","003","0010","88101",1,30.498001,-87.881412,"NAD83","PM2.5 - Local Conditions","24 HOUR","PM25 24-hour 2006","2013-01-04","Micrograms/cubic meter (LC)","None",1,100.0,7.6,7.6,0,32,"R & P Model 2025 PM2.5 Sequential w/WINS - GRAVIMETRIC","FAIRHOPE, Alabama","FAIRHOPE HIGH SCHOOL, FAIRHOPE,  ALABAMA","Alabama","Baldwin","Fairhope","Daphne-Fairhope-Foley, AL","2014-02-11"
"01","003","0010","88101",1,30.498001,-87.881412,"NAD83","PM2.5 - Local Conditions","24 HOUR","PM25 24-hour 2006","2013-01-07","Micrograms/cubic meter (LC)","None",1,100.0,8.6,8.6,0,36,"R & P Model 2025 PM2.5 Sequential w/WINS - GRAVIMETRIC","FAIRHOPE, Alabama","FAIRHOPE HIGH SCHOOL, FAIRHOPE,  ALABAMA","Alabama","Baldwin","Fairhope","Daphne-Fairhope-Foley, AL","2014-02-11"
"01","003","0010","88101",1,30.498001,-87.881412,"NAD83","PM2.5 - Local Conditions","24 HOUR","PM25 24-hour 2006","2013-01-10","Micrograms/cubic meter (LC)","None",1,100.0,7,7,0,29,"R & P Model 2025 PM2.5 Sequential w/WINS - GRAVIMETRIC","FAIRHOPE, Alabama","FAIRHOPE HIGH SCHOOL, FAIRHOPE,  ALABAMA","Alabama","Baldwin","Fairhope","Daphne-Fairhope-Foley, AL","2014-02-11"
```

*Note: Converting the CSV file to a tab delimited file makes it easier for MATLAB to deal with and circumvents this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the file exchange code `replaceinfile` to replace the strings that have commas in them with a period instead. 
Use `read_mixed_csv` from [Import CSV file with mixed data types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4747834/import-csv-file-with-mixed-data-types) to read in the file. 
Remove the extra quotes from the strings that are still left.

```
replaceinfile(', ', '. ', fname); % Replace commas that was inside quotes and not meant to be separated as periods so they don't show up as a new column
thisdata = read_mixed_csv(fname, ','); % Reads in the CSV file (\t for tab)
thisdata = regexprep(thisdata, '^"|"$',''); % Remove quotes from file and only keep the first 28 columns (last two columns are empty)
```

For `replaceinfile.m` function:
For running the code on Linux, change the first line of the section on Perl to

```
perlCmd = sprintf('"%s"', '/usr/bin/perl');
```

Answer (score 1):

Having a text qualifier (like `"`) is a little tricky, but the following might work if you ensure that each row of your table will have the same number of columns (and probably no empty ones).

**Anything not within the text qualifier must be convertible to a number.**

```
function C = csvmixed(eachLine,delim,textQualifier)
% Outputs cell containing mixed string and numeric data given a delimiter (',') 
% and a text qualifier ('"').  Each line of the delimited file must be loaded into 
% the cell array eachLine, and each line must have the same number of columns.
% 
% Example:
%   fid = fopen('testcsv.txt','r');
%   eachLine = textscan(fid,'%s','Delimiter','\n'); fclose(fid);
%   C = csvmixed(eachLine{1},',','"')

assert(ischar(delim) && numel(delim)==1);
assert(ischar(textQualifier) && numel(textQualifier)==1);

% find strings, as specified by the input qualifier
patternStr = sprintf('"([^"]*)"%c?',delim);
patternStr = strrep(patternStr,'"',textQualifier);
Cstr = regexp(eachLine,patternStr,'tokens');

% find numeric data
patternNum = sprintf('(?<=(,|^))[^%c,a-zA-Z]*(?=(,|$))',textQualifier);
patternNum = strrep(patternNum,',',delim);
Cnum = regexp(eachLine,patternNum,'match','emptymatch');

numCols = cellfun(@numel,Cstr) + cellfun(@numel,Cnum);
assert(nnz(diff(numCols))==0,'Number of columns not consistent.')

% get string extents (begin, start) indexes for each string
strExtents = regexp(eachLine,patternStr,'tokenExtents');

% deal out parsed data for each line
C = cell(numel(eachLine),numCols(1));
for ii = 1:numel(eachLine),
    strBounds = vertcat(strExtents{ii}{:});
    delimLocs = getDelimLocs(eachLine{ii},strBounds,delim);
    strCellMap = getCellMap(strBounds,delimLocs);

    C(ii,strCellMap) = [Cstr{ii}{:}]; % TODO: preallocate
    C(ii,~strCellMap) = num2cell(str2double(Cnum{ii})); % all else must be numeric
end

end

function delimLocs = getDelimLocs(lineText,solidBounds,delim)
    delimCharLocs = strfind(lineText,delim);
    delimLocs = delimCharLocs(~any(bsxfun(@ge,delimCharLocs,solidBounds(:,1)) & ...
        bsxfun(@le,delimCharLocs,solidBounds(:,2)),1));
end

function cellMap = getCellMap(typeBounds,delimLocs)
    cellMap = any(bsxfun(@gt,typeBounds(:,1),[0 delimLocs]) & ...
        bsxfun(@lt,typeBounds(:,1),[delimLocs Inf]), 1);
end
```

**UPDATE**: Fix small typos in `getDelimLocs`.  Add preallocation of cell array.

Comment: This worked for a couple of my files which were small. But then it started giving me an "Error in csvmixed (line 34)
    C(l,~strCellMap) = num2cell(str2double(Cnum{l})); % all else must be numeric." The files are basically identical in format. Do you have any idea what the error is referring to? Here is one of the files: https://www.dropbox.com/s/c5ece8pjsg6sag4/daily_88101_1999.csv?dl=0

Comment: @shizishan Your file is not finished uploading according to the link, but I can tell you it has to do with this: "**Anything not within the text qualifier must be convertible to a number.**"  Look for non-numeric data that is not in quotes.  Separate logic can be added to deal with non-numeric but it gets more complicated and slower.

Comment: I've been trying to see if that is the issue, but it doesn't look like any part of the file is different. I realized that for the year 2000, it stops after all the `01` `097` `2005` ones (the first three columns that tell me which site the data is from). I'll keep trying, but if you get the chance, I put the file for 2000 here. It should work this time: https://mega.co.nz/#!jYswjYDZ!E1roUeD1uNlbk92r_amYV8CSp0YJwmwaD1CKTz2C_7I

Comment: @shizishan There was a small error. The code did not handle strings that ended in a comma (e.g. `"501 W. VALLEY BLVD., BIG BEAR CITY,"`). It's fixed.  FYI, the output cell for that file is about 580 MB.

Comment: @shizishan Not sure, I only have 2014 versions installed.

Comment: I finally had MATLAB 2014 installed. I'm getting either 'Error using csvmixed (line 25)
Assertion failed.' Or, if I comment that line out, 'Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch.

Error in csvmixed (line 38)
    C(ii,~strCellMap) = num2cell(str2double(Cnum{ii})); % all else must be numeric'. Can you explain?

Comment: @shizishan what's the command line you used to call the function?  Also what's the input file? Can you post it?

Comment: I used the exact command you had in the code comments. I just changed the filename to reflect my file. https://www.dropbox.com/s/9k2bskl499w79fk/daily_44201_1980.csv?dl=0

Comment: Do you know why the file, when read out, is so large in MATLAB?

Comment: I didn't account for empty numeric fields (i.e. `,,`). Fixed, I think, and they will now be `NaN`.  Still quite slow and memory hungry.  Several factors affect size: in MATLAB a char is 2 bytes instead of 1, all numeric data is double precision using 8 bytes per value, the cell array itself has storage requirements too.