# Matlab: loading every n-th column of a csv with varying formats in row using textscan

Tags: matlab

i am trying to load a csv file with semicolon (;) delimiter.

Example:

```
150501;190722;ms_since_start=;30001276;temp=;31.97;IT=;147753;spec num=;1000;(here i have 512 floating number repetitions and ';;' to indicate the end of line)
```

this pattern repeats for 1000 rows.

I have been trying to use textscan but only get empty cells with the following code

```
formatSpec = ['%s%s%*s%*s%*s%*s%*s%*s%*s%*s%*s' repmat('%f', [1,512]) '%*[^;;]']
M = textscan(dirtmp, formatSpec, 'Delimiter', ';')
```

The goal is to get the first 2 columns, skip 9, get the remaining 512 columns and repeat this for 1000 rows.

Any help is highly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the answer to this question [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4747834/import-csv-file-with-mixed-data-types). I don't think you can actually skip the column but once you get the output you can say:

```
x = read_mixed_csv('example.csv',';');
y = x{:, [1,2, 11:size(x, 2)]};
```