# How can I get around MATLAB's specifications of csvread?

Tags: matlab, csv

I am trying to create a program that takes in multiple csv files. However, they include both strings and numbers.
I have csv files that looks something like this:

```
    "Project","Task","Value Type", "Value"
    "105", "06.05.02", "cost", "3434"
    "105", "06.05.02", "obligation", "3434"
    "106", "06.05.02", "cost", "500"
    "106", "06.05.02", "obligation", "500"
```

The number of columns is fixed (there are actually 23, I only listed four for readability), but each csv has a different number of rows. If I save it as an xls file, it works perfectly. However, this takes too long if there is a lot of files and the end user doesn't want to deal with that.

Similar questions suggested `textread`, but the first row would be

```
    textread('filename.csv', '%s%s%s%s', 'delimiter', ',');
```

while the rest of the file is

```
    textread('filename.csv', '%f%s%s%f', 'delimiter', ',');
```

In comparison to the simplicity of having the numbers, strings, and raw data in corresponding arrays using `xlsread`, having 23 different arrays seems a bit complicated.

What would be the best solution here?
The files are large, but not large enough that I am worried about efficiency.

Is there a way to change the extension of the files from .csv to .xls from within my program? (I looked this up as well, but couldn't find anything that worked) I would really like to use `xlsread`, but if this isn't possible, is there a way to have `textread` save the first row of a csv with certain variable types(`%s%s%s%s`) and then save the rest of the rows with a different variable type (`%f%s%s%f`)?

Comment: What about readtable (http://au.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/readtable.html)

Comment: @EliAlgranti - `readtable` only exists for MATLAB R2013b+.  The OP may not have a more recent version of MATLAB.

Comment: Look at this previous post [read_mixed_csv][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4747834/import-csv-file-with-mixed-data-types

Comment: You have to put your `textread(...)` line in a loop anyway, so why not just call your header `textread` before the loop and then get the data using your second `textread` inside the loop?

Comment: Thank you, some of these seem like they will work. I was using `textread` incorrectly, I figured since MATLAB is matrix-based I wouldn't need to use a loop and just automatically get each column. So.. is there no way to change a .csv to a .xls from within MATLAB? I just really want to use `xlsread` it's so much simpler to save all that data at once!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`xlsread` **does** read `csv` files, so there should be no need to convert. Just read directly (tested on 2013b with a small file of mixed numeric and string data):

```
[num, text, alldata] = xlsread('test.csv')
```

Note: this apparently only works on Windows machines.  If just changing the extension makes `xlsread` work for you, you can rename with `movefile`:

```
oldfile = somefile.csv;
ext = 'xls';
[~, name, ~ ] = fileparts(oldfile);
newfile = [name,ext];
movefile(oldfile,newfile);
```

If you have many files, this would go in a loop and `oldfile` would be taken from the output of something like a `dir` or `ls` command giving you all the .csv files.

Incidentally, while you might see it mentioned in older questions, `textread` is now not recommended, use `textscan` instead for cases where you need more complexity/control over the input. It can be very powerful but for this case is probably like cracking a nut with a sledgehammer.

If you don't need the headers, for example, you can take the whole file in one line with:

```
C = textread('filename.csv', '%f%s%s%f', 'Delimiter', ',','HeaderLines',1);
```

Comment: When attempting to read the `csv` file, I get this error: `Error using xlsread (line 247)
Unable to read XLS file SUMMARY_EXPORT.csv. File is not in recognized format.` If I manually change the extension to `.xls`, `xlsread` works perfectly.

Comment: I tried this, but each row was saved into a single column instead of the 23 constituent columns making up each row. I think there is something weird with the files that were exported from a different program. If I open them in Excel, and then reopen them with Text Wrangler, the quotes around each value disappear. That's a problem because some of the values include commas, which is the delimiter. Anyways, I guess the problem is my files, not MATLAB.