# How to load a cell array that has both strings and numbers?

Tags: matlab, load, cell-array

I have a cell array that has both strings and numbers. I want to load all the elements of the cell array. For the same I used the following method:

```
load(filename);
```

This command is loading only strings and excluding the columns that has numbers. Basically since my file is not `.mat` extension, it is treating it as ASCII file and loading only text.

I tried `importdata(filename)`. But that gives me struct of `1*1`. I need the elements to be imported into another cell array of same dimension.

Is there a way to load all the values?

Comment: `load` is for loading `.mat` files as you note in your question. See the help for `textscan` and see if that will work better.

Comment: The accepted answer of this post has a great function

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4747834/import-csv-file-with-mixed-data-types

Answer (score 0):

`load` is used to import `.mat`-files with workspace variables. Since your data is not an actual `.mat`-file, you need to use a different method.

Let's assume you have the file `filename` with tab-delimited data:

```
str1    1
str2    2
str3    3
str4    4
```

---

To get a cell-array where the first column is a string (using `%s`) and the second a double (using `%f`), you can use `textscan`. Check out the result, maybe it's already what you're searching for.

```
filename = 'data';
F = fopen(filename, 'r');
data = textscan(F, '%s %f', 'Delimiter', '\t');
```

---

If not, you can create a cell-array `CA` where the first column is a string (using `cellstr`) and the second one is a double (using `num2cell`).

```
CA = cell(size(data{1},1),2);
CA(:,1) = cellstr(data{1});
CA(:,2) = num2cell(data{2});
```

*Result:*

```
CA = 
    'str1'    [1]
    'str2'    [2]
    'str3'    [3]
    'str4'    [4]
```