# MATLAB: Import NA's as NaN in csvread()

Tags: matlab, nan

I have a number of large CSVs (hundreds with millions of rows) that I need to import in MATLAB so I am using csvread() to import my data as it's *almost* entirely numeric and to my knowledge csvread() is the fastest way to import the data and doesn't truncate the file. There's an occasional NA in my data so I am currently getting the error "Trouble reading 'Numeric' field from file". How do I get MATLAB to read these NAs as NaN?

This was marked as duplicate with the similar question how to [Import CSV file with mixed data types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4747834/import-csv-file-with-mixed-data-types) except that I would argue that my data is all numeric but that MATLAB is not correctly identifying the few NaNs (1/billion). I should clarify though, my main priority is optimizing for speed and any solution that is slower than manually editing the offending CSVs (there are 10000 of 1000000 rows) won't work for this application.

Comment: [`readtable`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/readtable.html) allows you to specify "empty" values with the [`'TreatAsEmpty'`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/readtable.html#btx_238-1-TreatAsEmpty) NV pair, MATLAB sets these values to `NaN`, which you can postprocess as necessary.

Comment: I think all your possible options are covered in the linked duplicate. You'll just have to see which one is fastest for your case.

Comment: Wow that's actually faster than the way I was doing it before. I used it in conjunction with table2array(readtable(filename, 'TreatAsEmpty', {'.', 'NA'})) and my test data ran 60 seconds faster!